# Xcode - no such module alamofire

Tags: alamofire

I manually added Alamofire framework to my XCode project, but when I build then it says cannot find Alamofire (at the import code line). If I build again, then the compile process gives an error but at a different code line. So after 4-5 tries the compile finished successfully and the program runs.

Unfortunatelly this "trick" doesn't work when I'd like to archive the program. The xcode gives the same error at the same codeline:

no such module alamofire

I already checked the older topics, but most of them seems outdated. I tried to add the project directory to the framework search path (recursive), no luck.

I use the newest Xcode and no dependency managers.

Answer (score 0):

uninstall cocoapods in terminal and reinstall again. Then go for install pod. Check the pod file everything right entered. After this try to build instead of run.